# Vue Apollo: Missing attribute on result

Tags: mongodb, vuejs2, vue-apollo

I'm new to Vue Apollo, and am getting stuck on what seems to be a common newbie challenge. I've checked out this post ([missing attribute on result, Vue, Apollo and GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468031/missing-attribute-on-result-vue-apollo-and-graphql)) which is the issue of making sure all the names match, but I don't seem to have the same issue (at least I don't think I do).

The issue is that it is just returning an empty "note" array. It's not getting the data from MongoDB, even through the exact same query works in the MongoDB sandbox.

Also, I haven't quite figured out how to insert the headers to get the data, so I'm just manually put that into the browser, which is working.

Here is the Vue Component Code:

```
<template>

  <div>

    <div>
      <h2>Hey there.</h2>
    </div>

    <div v-for="item in note" v-bind:key="item._id">
      <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    </div>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  apollo: {
    note: gql` query {
            note: elements {
              _id
              elements
              mode
              title
              type
              uri
              value
            }
          }`
  }
}
</script>

<style> 
</style>
```

And here are the dependences of the project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-beta.11"
  },
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thank you.